# How to free memory allocated by LWJGL

Tags: java, memory, lwjgl

My Java application with LWJGL allocates memory indefinitely until the application is dropped. Apparently this part of the code is causing the allocation of memory in looping. Is there a memory release missing?
Tks for help.

```
public void renderMesh(GameObject object, Camera camera) {
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(object.getMesh().getVAO());
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.getMesh().getIBO());
    
    shader.bind();
    shader.setUniform("model", Matrix4f.transform(object.getPosition(), object.getRotate(), object.getScale()));
    shader.setUniform("view", Matrix4f.view(camera.getPosition(), camera.getRotation()));
    shader.setUniform("projection", window.getProjectionMatrix());
    
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL13.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, object.getMesh().getMaterial(0).getTextureID());

    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, object.getMesh().getIndices().length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    shader.unbind();
    
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is nothing explicitly freeable. But there are possibly two elements :

1. Are you sure to free resources and buffers used by meshes of your object ?
2. And did you delete your shader program after use ?